# How can I test importing required modules after installing via pip?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

I am automating the creation of a virtualenv and then installing modules from a requirements file via `pip` (and its `-r` option).

I have found that some modules install successfully but have errors importing from within the environment.

After the requirements are installed how can I test importing all of the modules that are listed in the `requirements.txt`?

Comment: A quick&dirty way would be `python -m module` and check for the return value, but of course, that requires that the module in question can run non-interactively... (and also that the *script* itself returns 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requirements.txt` doesn't list modules (the import namespace), it lists “distributions” (the PyPI namespace). That said, you could use [pkg_resources](http://packages.python.org/distribute/pkg_resources.html) to list all the modules and try to import them:

```
import pkg_resources, setuptools

for dist in pkg_resources.working_set:
    for pkg in setuptools.find_packages(dist.location):
        __import__(pkg)
```

It still needs a way to go from “packages” (distutils terminology) to modules.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that was part of my question. I'll look into pkg_resources.

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
$ python -c "import os"
```

And then check for the exit status (`$?`)?

Comment: Well right, I can manually test importing modules but the point is I'm building different virtualenvs with different requirements and only want to test the modules required for that virtualenv. It looks like I need to use pkg_resources to get the module info and then test importing.